# How can I combine two arrays into one by _id in mongoDB and set to a specific field?

Tags: mongodb, lookup

Using $lookup, I was able to get the following document:

```js
{
   art: [
      {
         art: ObjectId("123"),
         public: false
      },
      {
         art: ObjectId("321"),
         public: true
      }
   ],

   artFoundByLookup: [
      {
         _id: ObjectId("123"),
         name: "Art 1"
         artist: "Artist 1"
      },
      {
         _id: ObjectId("321"),
         name: "Art 2"
         artist: "Artist 2"
      }
   ]
}
```

I want to combine the two arrays to make just one named "art" but with all of the information. If I set the "as:" value to be "art" it overwrites whether the art is public or not. So the result I am looking for should look like:

```js
{
art: [
      {
         _id: ObjectId("123"),
         name: "Art 1"
         artist: "Artist 1",
         public: false
      },
      {
         _id: ObjectId("321"),
         name: "Art 2"
         artist: "Artist 2",
         public: true
      }
   ]
}
```

There are other fields in this document besides "art" and "artFoundByLookup", I just left those fields out to avoid clutter. I am not sure if that has any impact on the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can achieve this with following query, you need `$map` and `$filter` for this to loop over one array and find in other array after finding just merge two objects. [Working solution](https://mongoplayground.net/p/q0rgXFMFVzO)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      Entities: {
        $map: {
          input: "$art",
          as: "e",
          in: {
            $mergeObjects: [
              "$$e",
              {
                $arrayElemAt: [
                  {
                    $filter: {
                      input: "$artFoundByLookup",
                      as: "j",
                      cond: {
                        $eq: [
                          "$$e.art",
                          "$$j._id"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  0
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      art: "$Entities"
    }
  }
])
```